# K3S arm64 distributed files systems

Tags: docker, kubernetes, glusterfs, distributed-filesystems, go

I deployed a K3S Cluster on arm64 and I need to have a DFS directly on-premise, It will be better to have it running on the kubernetes stack.
Regarding DFS choices there are some options, but...:

**GlusterFS**: Unfortunately CSI drivers is not currently supported on arm64.

**CephFS**: Unfortunately CSI drivers is not currently supported on arm64.

**Longhorn**: Only on armf.

**OpenEBS**: Dunno, did not test yet.

**Rook**(Ceph): CSI drivers not supported on arm64.

I tried to rebuild Docker image and binaries inside to be compatible on arm64 for Gluster and Ceph, but the point to failure seems to be the driver of course.

PS: in-tree drivers are being deprecated.

Do you have advices, solutions and documentations concerning my needs to have a DFS on k8s,k3s arm64 cluster?

Thank you have a good day.

Comment: Have you considered using NFS? I know NFS is not exactly a DFS solution but depending on what you want to achieve, it may be a good option. Check the answer on [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/990520) case to check how to implement this solution.

Comment: Our use case and environment does not allow us to have additional storage server for storage centralised (HA, backup....). So yes, I thought about this but for now I can not propose this solution.

Comment: But you can use a [pod](https://gist.github.com/matthewpalmer/0f213028473546b14fd75b7ebf801115) for that purpose.

Comment: You mean to have local storageclass? Yes, but I need to code all the sync between my nodes. Plus, I will not have the advantages of DFS with the option of storage block, recover, backup and hight availability...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s work in progress to build OpenEBS’ JIVA storage engine on ARM64 arch:
https://github.com/openebs/openebs/issues/1295

Comment: Thank you I will test it.

Answer (score 2):

OpenEBS works on arm64 but it's very slow. 
I've been having good results with https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner connected to nfs-ganesha that you can setup in active-active manner backed by glusterFS (https://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator-Guide/NFS-Ganesha-GlusterFS-Integration/).

Thanks,